# Windows 10 Pro: Hyper-V not in Windows Features

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I've got a new HP laptop which supports virtualization and is enabled in the BIOS. (HP Omen, 6th gen i7 quad core cpu)

It came pre-loaded with Win 10 Home, but I have purchased via the MS Store and upgraded it to Win 10 Pro.

I know the upgrade to Pro was a success as BitLocker is available.

I know the hardware prerequisites are met, because I get all "Yes" answers when running 'systeminfo' in PowerShell as per this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements

However if I run the command to enable Hyper-V, the error in PowerShell is that the module is unknown, and if I check via GUI there is simply no Hyper-V listed in "Turn Windows Features on or off".

Microsoft Support has so far not been any help, simply referring me back to the original support page to try to get through to the 'right' team.

Any ideas on how to enable Hyper-V?

Comment: You don't suppose that you accidently installed the 32bit version of Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is slightly embarrassing.

I thought everything was up to date, indeed windows update status specifically said no updates were available and checking revealed nothing. I had rebooted the machine a good dozen times after the Home-Pro upgrade too, so it certainly seemed like the upgrade was complete. 
However this morning after a huge round of automatic updates (rolleyes), Windows has kindly installed the Hyper-V module which I have now successfully enabled via the GUI.

To answer the questions posed: yes I'm absolutely certain that I'm running x64 and yes, it is definitely, absolutely Windows 10 Pro.

As a side note, Windows also took it upon itself to uninstall my docking station as the software doesn't work with this version of Windows, which is clearly a load of nonsense because I've just reinstalled it using the original executable and everything is fine.

So to answer my original question: the upgrade looks like it's complete but just like services that say they're running but clearly are not, in typical Microsoft fashion Windows is lying to you. Keep rebooting and checking for updates and eventually you'll hit the mother of all Windows Updates and it'll all work (sans any third party software you've installed which the MS developers have automatically removed because they collectively have a terrible sense of humour).

Thanks very much for the input however, it's much appreciated! :)

Comment: Windows feature updates uninstall software that could cause a problem.  Microsoft would rather uninstall software then cause problems that cannot easily be solved (i.e. BSOD upon profile login).

Comment: Similar here. Freshly installed Windows 10 Enterprise. It had already updated some things. There is no Hyper-V Manager. I forced to update some other things. Next time I've started the Windows, the H. Manager was there.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Downloading the Windows 10 Pro installation media using the [download
  tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Burning it to DVD
- Running a repair install, as mentioned
  here:[How To Reinstall Windows 10](https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/)

I got the idea from Microsoft forum: [There are features missing from Pro](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/592a8ba4-e4d6-4a2b-b07a-ddf972beee92/upgraded-windows-10-home-to-windows-10-pro-there-are-features-missing-from-pro-acting-like-its?forum=win10itprosetup)

Comment: Your comment above looks like it would make a good answer, if you add the download link contained in my link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10).  I wanted to leave the advice as a comment, but there wasn't enough reputation to do that.

Comment: Should I paste your answer from the comments into my answer?  It feels like I'd be stealing from you. I don't really care about the points, but if the site rules say my answer has to be complete that would work.